# How to view the code in the right color in sublime text?

Tags: php, sql, sublimetext

The code works fine, but it looks weird when I view it in Sublime text. After the INSERT INTO wp_options VALUES("462"  the following code code looks different.

[image]

This is the code causing the another color. Is there any problem with it?

```
INSERT INTO wp_options VALUES("462","wpcf-custom-types","a:2:{s:14:\"music-playlist\";a:25:{s:6:\"labels\";a:12:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Musics\";s:13:\"singular_name\";s:14:\"music-playlist\";s:7:\"add_new\";s:7:\"Add New\";s:12:\"add_new_item\";s:10:\"Add New %s\";s:9:\"edit_item\";s:7:\"Edit %s\";s:8:\"new_item\";s:6:\"New %s\";s:9:\"view_item\";s:7:\"View %s\";s:12:\"search_items\";s:9:\"Search %s\";s:9:\"not_found\";s:11:\"No %s found\";s:18:\"not_found_in_trash\";s:20:\"No %s found in Trash\";s:17:\"parent_item_colon\";s:11:\"Parent text\";s:9:\"all_items\";s:9:\"All items\";}s:4:\"slug\";s:14:\"music-playlist\";s:11:\"description\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"icon\";s:14:\"playlist-audio\";s:6:\"public\";s:6:\"public\";s:13:\"menu_position\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"menu_icon\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"taxonomies\";a:1:{s:8:\"post_tag\";s:1:\"1\";}s:8:\"supports\";a:1:{s:5:\"title\";s:1:\"1\";}s:7:\"rewrite\";a:6:{s:7:\"enabled\";s:1:\"1\";s:6:\"custom\";s:6:\"normal\";s:4:\"slug\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"with_front\";s:1:\"1\";s:5:\"feeds\";s:1:\"1\";s:5:\"pages\";s:1:\"1\";}s:11:\"has_archive\";s:1:\"1\";s:16:\"has_archive_slug\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"show_in_menu\";s:1:\"1\";s:17:\"show_in_menu_page\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"show_ui\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"publicly_queryable\";s:1:\"1\";s:10:\"can_export\";s:1:\"1\";s:17:\"show_in_nav_menus\";s:1:\"1\";s:17:\"query_var_enabled\";s:1:\"1\";s:9:\"query_var\";s:0:\"\";s:16:\"permalink_epmask\";s:12:\"EP_PERMALINK\";s:14:\"wpcf-post-type\";N;s:8:\"_builtin\";b:0;s:18:\"_toolset_edit_last\";i:1447908815;s:15:\"_wpcf_author_id\";i:1;}s:8:\"journals\";a:25:{s:8:\"_builtin\";b:0;s:18:\"_toolset_edit_last\";i:1448511352;s:15:\"_wpcf_author_id\";i:1;s:14:\"wpcf-post-type\";s:8:\"journals\";s:6:\"labels\";a:12:{s:4:\"name\";s:8:\"Journals\";s:13:\"singular_name\";s:7:\"Journal\";s:7:\"add_new\";s:7:\"Add New\";s:12:\"add_new_item\";s:10:\"Add New %s\";s:9:\"edit_item\";s:7:\"Edit %s\";s:8:\"new_item\";s:6:\"New %s\";s:9:\"view_item\";s:7:\"View %s\";s:12:\"search_items\";s:9:\"Search %s\";s:9:\"not_found\";s:11:\"No %s found\";s:18:\"not_found_in_trash\";s:20:\"No %s found in Trash\";s:17:\"parent_item_colon\";s:11:\"Parent text\";s:9:\"all_items\";s:9:\"All items\";}s:4:\"slug\";s:8:\"journals\";s:11:\"description\";s:17:\"life\\\'s a journey\";s:4:\"icon\";s:10:\"admin-post\";s:6:\"public\";s:6:\"public\";s:13:\"menu_position\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"menu_icon\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"taxonomies\";a:1:{s:8:\"post_tag\";s:1:\"1\";}s:8:\"supports\";a:1:{s:5:\"title\";s:1:\"1\";}s:7:\"rewrite\";a:6:{s:7:\"enabled\";s:1:\"1\";s:6:\"custom\";s:6:\"normal\";s:4:\"slug\";s:0:\"\";s:10:\"with_front\";s:1:\"1\";s:5:\"feeds\";s:1:\"1\";s:5:\"pages\";s:1:\"1\";}s:11:\"has_archive\";s:1:\"1\";s:16:\"has_archive_slug\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"show_in_menu\";s:1:\"1\";s:17:\"show_in_menu_page\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"show_ui\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"publicly_queryable\";s:1:\"1\";s:10:\"can_export\";s:1:\"1\";s:17:\"show_in_nav_menus\";s:1:\"1\";s:17:\"query_var_enabled\";s:1:\"1\";s:9:\"query_var\";s:0:\"\";s:16:\"permalink_epmask\";s:12:\"EP_PERMALINK\";}}","yes");
```

Comment: Looks like sublimes syntax highlighting is not recognizing `\` as an escape char - this looks like an SQL dump, which is not that common a file type to work on, so i dont know if this can be fixed with a setting

Comment: So that's mean if the code works fine. So I can leave the sublime color?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue starts at `\"life\\\'s a journey\"`

where the apostrophe `'` is what is changing the syntax highlighting, even though it is escaped..  Looks like it might be a bug in Sublime's SQL syntax highlighter.

Comment: You've got it. It looks like the SQL language definition doesn't recognize escaped double quotes, or escape sequences such as `\n` within them. However, escapes in single quoted strings work fine.

Comment: Does the SQL language definition (the official one, not Sublime's) support escapes in double-quoted strings?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time to look it up to answer definitively, but I would assume since his data appears to be from a MySQL-generated dump, and works fine when imported, that it's valid data, and encoded in a valid format.

Comment: Hmm. I'm googling for the answer, but haven't found anything yet. Perhaps I'll just change Sublime's syntax definition.

Comment: One thing that may be confusing at first is the fact that the escape sequence is obfuscated because the data that is stored in that column appears to be a serialized PHP array.  See this test example I just tried: http://pastie.org/10678044

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, I know very little about SQL or PHP (but I do know a lot about regexes and Sublime language definitions), so I'm not even sure what the string *should* look like :)

Comment: when i remove the whole INSERT INTO wp_options VALUES("462" at the end. It looks good on sublime.